# Typescript check if object contains one of many properties

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I'm building a method that receives a destructured object as argument:

```
class MyPoint() {
  ...

  set({ x = this.x, y = this.y, z = this.z }) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
```

The thing is I'm pretty happy with it but I just found a type bug not cached by Typescript:

```
const myPoint = new MyPoint();
myPoint.set(1);
```

Typescript takes it as valid because `1` is indeed an object which contains either `x`, `y` or `z`.

To capture this bugs I want to tell typescript: this object can have three optional properties: `x`, `y` or `z` but it **must** have at least one of them. All three are optional but at least one must be defined. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is quite verbose but works for now, hope there's a better way:

```
interface IXSetter {
  x: number;
  y?: number;
  z?: number;
}

interface IYSetter {
  x?: number;
  y: number;
  z?: number;
}

interface IZSetter {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
  z: number;
}

type PointSetter = IXSetter | IYSetter | IZSetter;

class MyPoint() {
  ...

  set({ x = this.x, y = this.y, z = this.z }: PointSetter) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
```

The error is clear now:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PointSetter'.
```